# How to extract a DTSHD audio stream from a mkv-file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a mkv-file, ripped from a bluray disk, containing multible audio streams, including a DTSHD-MA stream as stream 0:2. I'm trying to extract this stream from the mkv-file to an audio file, with the original format kept. However, I don't know for sure, which file extension to use for an audio file with DTSHD-MA audio. I red somewhere on the internet, that the extension was *.dtshd, so I tried with the following command:
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:2 output.dtshd

However, it didn't work, and ffmpeg gave the following message:
Unable to find a suitable audioformat.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I do it right?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards:
Aksel Christoffersen

Comment: You might consider open source *File Converter*, which has a GUI for ffmpeg and handles MKV as well as numerous other media types. It works under Windows, though I don't know about under Linux with wine or other OS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not interested in converting. I want to extract the original audio stream, and save it as a audio file in the original format.

Answer (score 2):

Use [mkvextract](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvextract.html) from the *mkvtoolnix* suite instead of `ffmpeg`, because it has been explicitly designed for that purpose:

```
sudo apt install mkvtoolnix
```

Its syntax is:

```
mkvextract source-filename tracks [options] TID1:dest-filename1 [TID2:dest-filename2 ...]
```

First, to determine the track number you want to extract, use the `mkvinfo` command

```
mkvinfo input.mkv
```

and look for the desired track number. You could extract any track (i.e. your DTSHD-MA track) if you know the track number (In this example I chose 3) and output it to a separate file:

```
mkvextract input.mkv tracks 3:output.dtshd
```

Now you should have your track in the `output.dtshd` file.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to use the `copy` command, otherwise `ffmpeg` would re-encode the track, so my command was:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:2 -c copy output.dtshd.
```